# Mysql Select All

Tags: php, forms, filter

In my database there are some vehicles with different categories and types. I want to create a form to filter vehicles by categories and types. So the form codes are as following.

```
<form action="" method="post">
Type <select name="search_type">
           <option value="jeep">Jeep</option>
           <option value="Wagon">Wagon</option>
           <option value="cab">Cab</option>
     </select>

Category <select name="search_category">
           <option value="Recondition">Recondition</option>
           <option value="Used">Used</option>
     </select>
    <input type="submit" name="search_submit"></form>
```

Here are the php code:

```
if(isset($_POST['search_submit']))
{
  $all_vehicles    = FALSE;
  $search_type     = $_POST['search_type'];
  $search_category = $_POST['search_category'];
  $search_brand    = $_POST['search_brand'];

  $search_result   = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM vehicle_info WHERE type='$search_type' && catagory='$search_catagory' && brand='$search_brand' ORDER BY id desc");
}
else
{
  $search_result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM vehicle_info ORDER BY id desc");
}
```

If someone wants to search `jeeps` with any category (used or recondition), what code I should write in the query?

I know I can add a new `<option>` as "ANY". But I don't know how to use it in the query.

Comment: code is okk then what is problm?

Comment: Your code is wide open to [SQL-Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection), also all `mysql_` functions have been deprecated in PHP, use `mysqli_` instead

Comment: Aren't you automatically searching both categories?

Comment: my problem is shown in the last lines of the questions :)

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://j.mp/PoWehJ).

Answer (score 1):

You dont have to store it as any. Just select it without the category. Assuming these are the only two categories stored, of course.

`SELECT * FROM vehicle_info WHERE type = '$search_type' ORDER BY id DESC;`

Also; please pay attention to SQL injections.

---

Edit in response at @dualed:

Correct. He could simply add `<option value="all">All categories</option>`

And add an if-statement:

```
if ($search_category != "all")
{
    $search_result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM vehicle_info WHERE type = '$search_type' AND category = '$search_category' ORDER BY id DESC;");
}
```

Comment: @Zac To expand on this answer: You will have to handle the case where a user selects "any" separately.

Comment: But what happen if there several input tags, like category, type, brand, price, model etc. actually i have many.Should I write if condition for all. So what happens someone left only 2 fields as "ANY" and try to filter other fields? example, he doesn't want to filter brand and type, but he wants to filter price and category.?

Comment: I think the simplest solution is to write if-statements checking if those information is submitted and build up your sql query before executing it. With `$sql .= "...more query..."` this is easly done. Summary: split up the query.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `IN()`

```
$search_result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM vehicle_info WHERE type IN('used', 'recondition') AND ...
```

See: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/de/comparison-operators.html

Answer (score 0):

```
 if(isset($_POST['search_submit']))
        {
            $all_vehicles=FALSE;
            $search_type = $_POST['search_type'];
            $search_category = $_POST['search_category'];
            $search_brand = $_POST['search_brand'];

            $query = "SELECT * FROM vehicle_info WHERE type='$search_type'";
            if(!empty($search_category)) {
               $query .= " && catagory='$search_catagory'";
            }
            if(!empty($search_brand)) {
                 $query .= " && brand='$search_brand'";
            }
            $query .= " ORDER BY id desc"


            $search_result = mysql_query($query);
        }
        else
        {
             $search_result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM vehicle_info ORDER BY id desc");
        }
```